# Transition from single node to multi node hadoop same

Tags: networking, hadoop

I've followed the hadoop single node installation steps from this [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) . And now following this [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) to connect them to make a multi-node cluster. I'm in the beginning of the steps and I just have a question, both my machines have the same username `userA` and they have a second `hduser`. How can I rename `userA` to make it named `master` on one machine and `slave` on the other?

Also I connected them with a wired cable, so they are on the same network, but I wonder how do I do this `configure the network interfaces to use a common network such as 192.168.0.x/24.` as I'm not good in networking.

So if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If the two machines are connected, just check their IP addresses and modify your /etc/hosts file on both the machines so as to make one machine the master and the other slave.

Say the IP addresses of the two machines are 10.25.5.114 and 10.25.5.115
and you want to make the 1st machine the master then update your /etc/hosts file on both the machines with the following lines:

10.25.5.114 master
10.25.5.115 slave

This assigns the IP address 10.25.5.114 to the master machine and 10.25.5.115 to the slave machine.